# Motion UI ListView android example

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Maybe someone knows/or found somewhere how to make this kind of list on android using kotlin?

https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/418188/screenshots/2182940/art_gallery_app.gif

I think it's similar to Material desgn:

https://material.io/design/components/lists.html#behavior

but I couldn't find anywhere is it cards layout or some expandable list view. So maybe someone experienced could tell me from where I should start to make list like in the first link?

Moreover for such transitions is it better to use Fragments or Activities?

Comment: If you are still searching here is a link that may help: https://proandroiddev.com/implement-google-inbox-style-animation-on-android-18c261baeda6

Comment: ok, that's a good one, but what you think can I make this transition for recycle view with cards? And using only activities? :)